# Plugin to obfuscate JS / jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, obfuscation

I've finished developing in terms of js / jQuery and I was wondering if there was a plugin that can obfuscate my javascript and jQuery code while still allowing it to work.

And if possible, not slow down load times that much.

Is there such a plugin?

Comment: If you minify your code it'll be smaller and somewhat obfuscated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @IanHunter It is already minified. I know that does it somewhat, but I was looking for something that makes it hard to tell what the working code is doing due to a bunch of other code that isn't actually executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of [How can I obfuscate (protect) JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

In short, the popular options are YUI Compressor, Google Closure Compiler, and UglifyJS.  They all do minification, so you might want to not use the minified version of your project that you mention in a comment.

I personally think that Google Closure Compiler is the most thorough, but hardest to use.

Comment: I was just reading the linked questions. How does one use Google Closure Compiler ?

Comment: The easiest way to get started is with this: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home  if you like the output, then see the download section here: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/  For maximum obfuscation, be sure to choose advanced optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

First choice is [YUI compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/), second is [uglifyjs](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs). 
The fist one is really good and popoular for minification (with makes obfuscuation also).

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of following tools:

- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [ShrinkSafe](http://dojotoolkit.org/docs/shrinksafe)
- [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)